# How to check whether the mouse left button is down or not while mouse move?

Tags: javascript, jquery, mouseevent

I have a below situation.

```
function mousemove(e){
if(left button clicked){
//drag the element
}
else{
//show the tooltip
}
}
```

Initially i have binded the mousemove function. while mouse moving i need to check
whether the left button is clicked or not. if clicked means i need to drag it. else means i need to show tooltip.

i searched a lot. i cant get the solution for all the browser,
I need to do this for IE8,IE9,IE10,IE11,Chrome, firefox and safari.
please help me...
thanks in advance..

Comment: Set dragging flag on `mousedown`, remove on `mouseup`. On `mousemove` drag if flag is `on`. Than your condition would be `if(flag){ ...drag... }`

Answer (score 1):

The event itself does not tell you if the button is being held, so you have to track it yourself using `mousedown` and `mouseup`, something like this:

```
var clickHeld = false;
$('#myElement').on({
    'mousemove': function() {
        if (clickHeld) {
            // a click & drag is happening, do what you require
        }
    },
    'mousedown': function() { clickHeld = true; },
    'mouseup': function() { clickHeld = false; }
});
```